# TableView of fetched data not refreshing if MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, mbprogresshud

I've got a weird one that I can't figure out and I'm hoping someone here will point me in the right direction:

I have a core data tableview application that drills down to a detail view where an image can be downloaded. Once the image is downloaded, when I back up one level into table view, a thumbnail is created and appears.

While in the detail view, the user has the option to download ALL images for the table view (using a passedFetchResultsController to cycle through each item, download the image, and assign it to the item.photo value). The thumbnail creation works fine here as well. In other words, if the user downloads all the images and then backs up one level to the table view, thumbnails are created (and appear) for every item in the table.

However, I would like to add MBProgressHUD to the detail view so that while the user is downloading the multiple images (could be 10, could be 100, could be 1000, depending on the table), the user sees a progress indicator letting them know the images are being downloaded.

If I use the MBProgressHUD, when the downloads are complete, the detail view updates with the correct image, but when I back up one level to the table view, the thumbnails do not appear (in fact, the "selected" cell remains highlighted, suggesting the table isn't refreshing at all). The thumbnails ARE being created (I can see that in my logs) and if I back up one more level, and then drill back down, all the thumbnails are there. So it appears to be the tableview is simply not refreshing if I use MBProgressHUD. I have generous log statements, and everything APPEARS to be running identically (the context is saved, "viewdidappear" runs, the thumbnail method runs, cellforrowatindexpath runs) but the thumbnails don't appear for the cells that were previously on the screen. If I scroll down, new cells that are created have the new thumbnails, but even when I scroll back up, the original cells do not have the thumbnails. If I drill down to each detail view, the image appears in the imageview, but going back to the table view still doesn't refresh the view... If I back up one more level and then drill back down, they are there again.

I will be happy to post code, but I'm not sure which part would be beneficial - if you have some thoughts and want to see some of the methods, please let me know and I'll post ASAP.

For clarification, here is my implementation of MBProgressHUD:

```
- (IBAction)httpMultipleImageDownload:(id)sender {


HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

// Add HUD to screen
[self.view.window addSubview:HUD];

HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Downloading Images";
HUD.detailsLabelText = @"This could take several minutes!";
HUD.square = YES;
HUD.minSize = CGSizeMake(320.f, 320.f);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(downloadTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

}
```

downloadTask is triggering the image downloads. If my button calls downloadTask directly, the images download, the detail view is refreshed, and when I back out to the tableView, all the thumbnails appear.

If I, instead, call the above method with the button press, the HUD is created and shows while executing the downloadTask. As before, all images download, the detail view is refreshed,but when I back out to the tableView the thumbnails DO NOT APPEAR. They are created, however, and if I back up another level, and then back down, they are visible. Does that make more sense?

Thanks!
Zack

Comment: how are you saying that MBProgressHUD is causing the issue? Leave all the code as is. Just comment that one line where you add showHUD above the view. Do the images start showing now? and adding it back,  surface the problem again?  When the cellForRow is called and the imageView is set, have you verified the image and the frame of the image view?

Comment: @hackerinheels I've updated my question above with some code, but to answer your question, yes. If I run the downloadTask directly from an IBAction button press, it works fine, thumbnails and all. If I call the task as part of the MBProgressHUD method, everything still downloads and the core data is updated correctly, but the thumbnails DO NOT refresh in the tableView (until I back out completely and drill back down). Thanks. Zack